# Why shouldn't I use striping raid on the partition I boot from?

Tags: raid, boot, gentoo

The [Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Gentoo_installation_tips_and_tricks#Software_RAID) says:

> You should not use any form of striping such as RAID-0 or RAID-5 on the partition you boot from.

Why is this? I've never seen a similar warning before. Grub supports booting from a raid0 disk, and the kernel supports it as long as the modules are compiled in. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Edit: Arch Linux's [section on raid](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RAID#Installing_Arch_Linux_on_RAID) mentions nothing in regards to *striped* raid in particular. Is this warning specific to Gentoo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your boot loader (e.g. grub) won't know how to read from RAID-0 or RAID-5. Where did you find information that grub supports raid0?

You should have a small RAID-1 /boot partition.

**UPDATE: I was wrong.**

Turns out grub [does support raid1 and raid5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28443/does-grub2-support-putting-boot-on-a-raid5-partition). However, there's some confusion about what metadata formats it supports, so I guess warning in the Gentoo guide is there for safety.

However, all the guides I've seen before say to use raid1, so raid1/raid5 does not seem like well tested configuration, so I'd still recommend to avoid it.

Comment: I don't know where I read that, seems your right; Thanks!

Comment: Aha! Here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#RAID "You may use mdadm for RAID 5/6, which is supported by GRUB."

Comment: @shelvacu huh, looks like I was wrong. I've edited my answer. TIL.